# lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods

Tags: clojure, lisp, read-eval-print-loop

I am learning clojure now, I wrote a file like this:

```
;; File ./mycode/myvoc.clj

(ns mycode.myvoc
    (:use 'clojure.java.io)
    (:import (java.io.File)))

; more code here...
```

this file resides in `./mycode/`, when I run REPL, I wanna use the function in `myvoc.clj`, like this:

```
user=> (use 'mycode.myvoc)
java.lang.Exception: lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods (myv
oc.clj:1)
```

I don't know why. if I change `myvoc.clj` as :

```
(ns mycode.myvoc)
;    (:use 'clojure.java.io)
;    (:import (java.io.File)))
```

It'll be ok but just report no "reader in this context" for I commented the import part.

Could somebody fix this? I alse use `require` but get the same kind of error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to remove the quote from your `:use` clause:

```
(ns mycode.myvoc
  (:use clojure.java.io)  ; note no '
  (:import java.io.File)) ; extra parens removed here; they do no harm,
                          ; though
```

`'clojure.java.io` is shorthand for `(quote clojure.java.io)`, so your original `:use` clause was

```
(:use (quote clojure.java.io))
```

This looks as if you were trying to `:use` a namespace with a prefix of `quote` and final segment `clojure.java.io`. The dots in the latter are the direct cause of the error from the point of view of `ns`.

Incidentally, it's much more usual to `(:require [clojure.java.io :as io])` and then say `io/file`, `io/reader` etc. than it is to pull in the entire namespace.

Finally, just to be clear, the quote is necessary when using the *function* `use` (like in your `(use 'mycode.myvoc)` call), as opposed to a `:use` clause in a `ns` declaration.

Comment: yes, thank you ,this is ok for me. I switched to use (:require ...) clause.